# Need help to build a regular expression to add '\n' within a long string

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm not quite familiar with regular expression, I need to insert several '\n' within a long string to make it multiple lines and more readable. The rule is quite simple: in the following paragraph:

> Aardvark Topsites is a popular free PHP Topsites script. Multiple
>   vulnerabilities have been found in the product allowing remote
>   attacker to disclosure sensitive information about the server and
>   inject malicious SQL statements. Solution : Upgrade to version 4.1.1
>   or newer.

whenever I see a dot . and a colon :, I want to insert a '\n' after the dot so that what's after the dot can become another paragraph. So ideally, the above sample after the change would look like:

> Aardvark Topsites is a popular free PHP Topsites script. Multiple
>   vulnerabilities have been found in the product allowing remote
>   attacker to disclosure sensitive information about the server and
>   inject malicious SQL statements.
>   Solution : Upgrade to version 4.1.1
>   or newer.

This string is retrieved from database and ultimately rendered on django template. My questions is: in which place of django should I deal with this? And how can I achieve that? Is there any other way besides regular expression that can also solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your before and after doesn't match up with the rule you provided... there are instances of `.` and `:` that didn't get a newline.

Comment: *“I'm not quite familiar with regular expression”* – What exactly makes you think that you *need* regular expression then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex to insert '\n' after dots and colons is quite dangerous, just think what would happen to your version string!

This may help: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks

Django has some tools to deal with linebreaks easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wrapped = re.sub(r'(.{60,}?[.:])\s+', r'\1\n', text.strip())
```

"60" is the desired average paragraph length